# Open protected word document with OpenXML

Tags: c#, openxml

I have searched every where but, I can't found any answer.
All posts and discussions are about creating protected one but nothing for open it.

I have protected DOCX and DOC documents in my c# program and want to open them programmatically using OpenXML 2.5.

I have opened them using Office interlope as it has password parameter.
But it's very slow with large documents number.

Can i open password protected word documents using OpenXml ? How ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Password protected documents (documents saved with a password) are not Zip packages, they're binary files. If you think about it, the reason is obvious: a Zip package of XML files is human-readable - not secure. So you can't manipulate password protected Word documents via the Open XML file format - it's simply not there.

Comment: So, There is no way without using Office interlope to open or make search inside documents faster ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to release the *lock* using `OpenXml`, by canceling the protection.
Found the answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1714119/9615200).

```cs
WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filePaths[i], true);
doc.ExtendedFilePropertiesPart.Properties.DocumentSecurity = new DocumentSecurity("0");
doc.ExtendedFilePropertiesPart.Properties.Save();
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.DocumentProtection dp =
doc.MainDocumentPart.DocumentSettingsPart
.Settings.ChildElements.First<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.DocumentProtection>();
```